# Binary operator "+" cannot be applied to operands of type "CGFloat" and "CGPoint" in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
obstacle1B.position = CGPointMake(square.size.width * 2 + obstacle1A.position, self.frame.size.height)
```

The error says: Binary operator "+" cannot be applied to operands of type "CGFloat" and "CGPoint"

I think I have to convert something to a CGFloat but I'm not sure. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`square.size.width * 2` is a `CGFloat` but `obstacle1A.position` is a `CGPoint`.

Perhaps you meant `obstacle1A.position.x` (or `obstacle1A.position.y`)?